# In a TFS 2012 WIT, is there a way to show the full comment dates for System.History instead of the "fuzzy" ones?

Tags: tfs

Having been using TFS 2012 for almost a year now, our team has started working on another round of customizations to our customized Agile Process Template.  I received a request today that I can't figure out.

In TFS 2012 (this seems to be a new thing), the System.History field in each WIT used for History comments displays a "fuzzy" date next to each update, rather than the full date-stamp that I believe was used in TFS 2010.  Is there a way to show the full date rather than "a few minutes ago," "4 weeks ago," etc.?

[image: Image showing issue]

Comment: You get the actual date in The tooltip. As in StackOverflow...

Comment: Thanks!  I noticed that this tooltop pops up in Web Access only.  I will leave the question open for a while to see if there's a way to bypass that.  I am guessing that this isn't something I can change, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten word from a good authority on TFS customization that this is not possible.  The workaround from KMoraz -- hovering over the fuzzy date for the time-stamp pop-up in Web Access -- is good enough for our team.